# I would like to use PostrgeSQL with .NET. How do I go about it?

Tags: .net, database, postgresql

I am working on a small practice project in .NET with Sql Server 2005. I want to learn PostgreSQL and implement my project in PostgreSQL in the final version. Please advise on all the things I need to do, to setup PostgreSQL with .NET and run it successfully.

Sincere thanks
fsck.

Comment: what's wrong with your keyboard?

Comment: Is there some joke here I'm just not getting, or should this just be flagged as spam?

Comment: Oh god, I am so sorry, I just did not check my title.

I am really really sorry. I don't know how this happened.

I hit submit and went away for sometime, so I could not check it until now.

Someone, please correct my error.

Sincere thanks.

Comment: EDIT: I realised I could change the title .
Please be kind and don't downmod me, it was a mistake and I corrected it.

Comment: and got rid of the not-programming-related tag.

Comment: Darn, now I missed my first chance to edit a community wiki :(. A never mind chances will propably keep coming ^^

Comment: Thanks Nathan W for your help. 

_Oh, I am such a noob here.._

Comment: Its all good, thats the joy of being able to fix up other peoples posts...also so they don't get downvoted into hell :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a postgres .Net data provider, [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/), that should be useful.